# Detect what cross compiler is running

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-embedded-compact

I am using VS2013 and a WEC2013 custom SDK to compile a program for a WEC2013 (ARM) device. The compiler is part of the SDK. Now I experience different behavior of the compilation on two different PCs.

1. The compiler puts .tlog output files in the same directory as the .ob output files at PC A. At PC B I find these .tlog files in a separate directory `ProjectName.SDK_Name.tlog`.
2. The compiler at PC A writes the files `vc110.pdb` and `vc110.idb` at the place where the .obj files are created. At the PC B I find instead `vc120.pdb` and `vc120.idb` at the same place.
3. The feature Code Analysis shows problems in the code at PC A but nothing at PC B.

It looks like there is a different compiler running on the two PCs. The `vc110.pdb` should be generated by the compiler included in the SDK because the SDK is generated with that platform. The `vc120.pdb` should be generated by a VS2013 compiler (internal version VC 12.0).

- How can I detect what cross compiler is actually running? The .tlog files include all compiler arguments, but not the compiler invocation.
- How can I control what cross compiler is invoked for compilation of the project? (The .vcxproj and all source files are identical on both PCs.)